# uploading Contiki programs into Micaz using MIB520

Tags: makefile, contiki

Recently I have some problems to upload a Contiki program into my Micaz mote.
I've used a MIB520 to do that, but it doesn't work. After doing some search inside Contiki configuration files, I found that the only Micaz Makefile provided is the one for MIB510: `Makefile.mib510` which can be found in `~/Contiki/platform/micaz/buildscripts`.

In the `Makefile.mib510` there is only the `uisp` command.

I would like to know if there is another one provided for MIB520.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to do that :

```
make TARGET=micaz program.upload PORT=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

where `program` is the name of the program you want to upload.

Here two helpful links to help you uploading programs on motes : [link1](http://alan-xuefei.blogspot.fr/2012/05/burn-mote-contiki-tinyos-micaz-telosb.html) and [link2](http://blog.163.com/hairong_yan/blog/static/798129562008416101630542).